# Echo value from database to selectize.js with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to echo out value from database with php for selectize.js.

Html code

```
<select id="type" placeholder="Type" name="type" required>
<!-- This option help to selected value from DB -->
<!--<option value="<?php echo $dataFromDB['type'] ?>" selected></option>-->
</select>
<button id="someType">Add Option</button>
```

Js code (example from selectizejs (with change))

```
var $select = $('#type').selectize({
maxItems: 1,
valueField: 'id',
labelField: 'days',
searchField: 'days',
options: [{
    id: '1',
    days: '5 days'
}, {
    id: '2',
    days: '2 days'
}, {
    id: '3',
    days: '1 days'
}],
create: true
});
var control = $select[0].selectize;
$('#someType').on('click', function () {
    control.addOption({
        id: '4',
        days: 'New Days'
    });
});
```

How to automatically add option from database value and set as selected option?

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/2zyp8jxn/)

Note: I could echo out the value to option if there's a match between database value and options value.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/2zyp8jxn/1/

```
control.setValue("4");
```

Create a variable with php:

```
 $php_test = "control.addOption({
                   id: '".$dataFromDB['type']."',
                   hari: '".$dataFromDB['type']."'
                 });
                 control.setValue('".$dataFromDB['type']."');
                ";
```

and add this jquery code

```
var control = $select[0].selectize;
$(function() {
   <?php echo 'var someOptions ='. $php_test ?>
});
```

I dont know if create a variable someOptions is necessary or not but it works for me.
Thanks

Comment: i dont want to press the button everytime to create  the option, any idea?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2zyp8jxn/2/ see the example, i write it on php. Dont know how to write that logic on jquery